# apache error "no macro defined before Use"

Tags: apache-2.4, perl, mod-perl

REVISED

I inherited this apache server from a Perl shop that I now work. When this web server was on ubuntu 14.04, I had no issues starting apache. I upgraded the server to ubuntu 18.04 and now apache does not start, here is the error

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 61 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vhost.conf: no macro defined before Use
```

line 225 of main apache config

```
224 # Include the virtual host configurations:
225 IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

line 61 of vhost file

```
    <IfModule perl_module>
    Use Pconf /home/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/htdocs 4 10 Hawaii
</IfModule>
```

This is where I am at a standstill, I have enabled the macro package.

```
  Module macro already enabled
```

I can't start apache so there are no errors in the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is trying to tell you that you need to define the macro Pconf before using a macro named Pconf.

The [mod_macro: Usage documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_macro.html#usage) has an example that should help get you going.